# If a bolt and a nut are selected at random, what is the probability that they will fit together?

Tags: self-study, mathematical-statistics, normal-distribution

Suppose that the diameters of the bolts in a large box follow a normal distribution with a mean of 2 centimeters and a standard deviation of 0.03 centimeter. Also, suppose that the diameter of the holes in the nuts in another large box follow a normal distribution with a mean of 2.02 centimeters and a standard deviation of 0.04 centimeter. A bolt and a nut will fit together if the diameter of the hole in the nut is greater than the diameter of the bolt and the difference between these diameters is not greater than 0.05 centimeters. **If a bolt and nut are selected at random, what is the probability they will fit together?**:

My working outs:

Denote the diameter of the bolt as $d_b$ and the diameter of the holes in the nuts as $d_n$.

Then the difference is given as $d_n-d_b = 2.02-2 = 0.02$
The variance: $var(d_n-d_b)=0.03^2+0.04^2=0.0025$

Given that a bolt and a nut are selected at random, then $n=2$, and we get: $Pr\left(\frac{\sqrt{2}(d_n-d_b-0.02)}{0.0025}<0.05\right)$.

However I have a few questions on the next steps after this to clear my doubts:

Q1. Do I divide the probability of $0.05$ by $\frac{\sqrt{n}}{\sigma}$ to get $\frac{0.05}{0.0025}\sqrt{2}$? What do I do with the difference value of$-0.02$

After having a look at the solutions, I should get the form: $Pr(-0.4<Z\le0.6)$, I cannot seem to find this result - any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Is this a homework question?

Comment: @Dave No! I'm reading probability and statistics by Degroot - I have only ever self-studied , and without a lecture it's rather difficult to make out some of the terse writing

Comment: What do you mean by the quantity "$n$"?  You contemplate *one* nut, *one* bolt, and the difference between them.  There doesn't seem to be any role for an "$n$" nor for the formula you have written.

Comment: Because this is self-study, you should tag it as [tag:self-study].

Comment: @whuber I see; I counted them as independently, a count of 1 nut and a count of 1 bolt, and assumed to sum the number of counts. It seems that I should remove the $\sqrt{2}$, although what's the next step into getting it into the form $-0.4<Z<0.6$, given that $Z = \frac{d_n-d_b-0.02}{0.0025}$? I had thought of $\pm0.02$ on the RHS, and dividing it by $\frac{1}{0.0025}$, but it does not provide me the the same range.

Comment: $Z = (x-\mu)/\sigma$ (note the difference between standard deviation and variance)

Comment: You want to find $\Pr(0 < d_n-d_b \le 0.05)$  and you know the mean and variance of $d_n-d_b$

Comment: @Henry I seem to get the result I'm after by following this: $\frac{-0.02}{0.05}<Z\le\frac{0.05-0.02}{0.05}=Pr(-0.4<Z\le0.6)$ However this is far from the calculations I had in mind, and it does not include the variance. To me this does not make sense, could someone confirm with me?

Comment: In $\frac{-0.02}{0.05}<Z\le\frac{0.05-0.02}{0.05}$ the denominator is the square root of the variance

Comment: @Henry Yes! I forgot to square the variance. Thanks for pointing that out, although given the LHS of the inequality, why is $d_n-d_b$ set as $0$?

Comment: "A bolt and a nut will fit together if the diameter of the hole in the nut is greater than the diameter of the bolt and ..."

Comment: @Henry Thanks, I just wanted to confirm my doubts as I had expected the answer to be given in that statement

Answer (score 2):

Thank you for showing your approach to this problem. I will let you resolve the sets and their probabilities.

Here is a simulation in R with a million nuts and a million bolts.
The probability of a fit seems to be about $0.381 \pm 0.001.$

```
 set.seed(2021)
 b = rnorm(10^6, 2,.03)
 n = rnorm(10^6, 2.02,.04)
 event.1 = (n > b)
 event.2 = (abs(n-b)<.05)
 fit = event.1 & event.2
 mean(fit)
 [1] 0.381237
 2*sd(fit)/1000
 [1] 0.0009713817
```

In the figure below green dots are in `event1` only;
blue dots are in `event2` only, and the red dots
are in the intersecting event `fit`. [Apparent areas may be deceptive because
the distribution of points is far from uniform.]

[image]

Addendum, R code for figure:

```
plot(n, b, pch=".")
points(n[event.1], b[event.1], pch=".", col="green")
 event.2 = (abs(n-b)<.05)
 points(n[event.2], b[event.2], pch=".", col="blue")
  fit = event.1 & event.2
  points(n[fit], b[fit], pch=".", col="red")
```

Comment: Thanks, @Henry. Typo in copying question into code. Fortunately, most of this was still in my R session window, so the repair was not difficult.